# Control may reach end of non-void function (checking for valid date)

Tags: c++

```
 bool isValidDate(int month, int day, int year) {
if(year <= 1752){
    if(month <= 9 && month <= 13){
        return false;
    }
    else{
    }
}
else{
    if((month == 9 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 11) && (day <= 30)){
        return true;
    }
    else if((month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day <= 31)){
        return true;
    }
    else if(isLeapYear(year)){
        if((month == 2) && (day <= 29)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if(!isLeapYear(year)){
        if((month == 2) && (day <= 28)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I'm trying to make it so that if users enter any date before Sept. 13, 1752, it will return false. And also if the days have to be correct according to the month while taking into account leap years for the month of February. But I keep getting an error. Help much needed.

Comment: If the year is less than or equal to 1752 and the month is greater than 9, what will happen? Think about this.

Comment: Yeah, then it wouldn't work. But I can't think of a way to avoid that problem

Comment: But in that case, or of the month is invalid (like 13; the compiler doesn't know that) then the control will fall out the bottom of the function without returning.  Hence the warning/error.